# How to get data for all rows in jqgrid with pagination

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to access grid data as below

```
    var namePresent;
    var datafromgrid = $('#MyGrid').jqGrid('getRowData');
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
         var name = datafromgrid[i].Name;
         var firstname = name.split(/ +/);
         if (firstname[0].toLowerCase() == Name.toLowerCase()) {
             namePresent = 1;
         }
    }
```

Now suppose when my grid is loaded with 5 records then this code throws error on line var `name = griddata[i].Name;` as from grid it is unable to read griddata[5].
Please tell me how to read whole grid data even if it is not visible on screen but is fetched successfully?

Answer (score 27):

you can try using :

```
var allRowsInGrid = $('#list4').jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
```

Comment: WOW!!! You are my HERO!!! Thank you very much!!! I have very customized grid where one cell can have multiple inputs and your code allows me to manipulate local data and then send them to server.

Answer (score 6):

This way is more "pretty":

```
var allRowsInGrid = $('#list4').getGridParam('data');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative way to get the data of a particular row. You can loop over all rows to get everything:

```
var dataIDs = grid.getDataIDs(); 
for(i = 0; i < dataIDs.length; i++)
{
    var rowData = grid.jqGrid ('getRowData', dataIDs[i]);
    //rowData is object containing keys & values for row
    console.log(rowData);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

After digging into the documentation, found this straight forward way.

```
var allRowsInGrid = $('#list4').getGridParam('data');
```

This returns you a JavaScript Array Object. To check the values in JS Object you can simply use following way.

```
var stringVersion = JSON.stringify(allRowsInGrid);

alert (stringVersion);
```